# cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Failed to instantiate class when run on other devices

Tags: java, android, maven, cucumber, appium

Please help me in this case.
I faced this error when trying to run the Cucumber steps with Appium using java on other devices.
Means that I can run the script correctly on **my device**, but when I connect to **other devices**, I faced this error.
 Although I was changed the capability: "*deviceName*" and "*platformVersion*".
Here is my Hooks:

```
    public class Hooks {
    private static AndroidDriver driver;
    private static String packageApp;


    @Before
    public static AndroidDriver openPaxApp(String appName){
        if(appName.equals("mycar")){
            packageApp = "com.mycar.passenger";
        }else if (appName.equals("pegasus")){
            packageApp = "com.qupworld.pegasuspax";
        }
        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability("deviceName", "42003cedd0e144d9");
        cap.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        cap.setCapability("platformVersion", "6.0.1");
        cap.setCapability("appPackage", packageApp);
        cap.setCapability("appActivity", "com.qup.pegasus.ui.launch.LauncherActivity");
        cap.setCapability("automationName", "UiAutomator2");
        cap.setCapability("autoGrantPermissions", "true");
        cap.setCapability("skipDeviceInitialization", "true");
        cap.setCapability("skipServerInstallation", "true");
        cap.setCapability("noReset", "true");
        try {
            driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
        } catch (
                MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        return driver;
    }
}
```

And here is my runner file:

```
package cucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.SnippetType;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;


@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/test/java/features",
        glue = "stepDefinitions",
        monochrome = true,
        plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/site/cucumber-report-default", "json:target/site/cucumber.json"},
        snippets = SnippetType.CAMELCASE,
        tags = {"@RegisterAndLogin, @HomePageTestCases"}
public class CucumberTestRunner {
}
```

Then I faced this error:

```
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Failed to instantiate class stepDefinitions.RegisterAndLoginSteps

    at cucumber.runtime.java.DefaultJavaObjectFactory.cacheNewInstance(DefaultJavaObjectFactory.java:47)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.DefaultJavaObjectFactory.getInstance(DefaultJavaObjectFactory.java:33)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:38)
    at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:37)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:300)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:44)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.ExecutionUnitRunner.run(ExecutionUnitRunner.java:102)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:63)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:18)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:330)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:328)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:65)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:292)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:305)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:412)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:70)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:95)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:38)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:330)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:328)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:65)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:292)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:305)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:412)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.run(Cucumber.java:100)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.DefaultJavaObjectFactory.cacheNewInstance(DefaultJavaObjectFactory.java:41)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: org.json.JSONException: No value for desiredCapabilities
    at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
    at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:609)
    at io.appium.uiautomator2.handler.request.BaseRequestHandler.getPayload(BaseRequestHandler.java:50)
    at io.appium.uiautomator2.handler.NewSession.safeHandle(NewSession.java:38)
    at io.appium.uiautomator2.handler.request.SafeRequestHandler.handle(SafeRequestHandler.java:37)
    at io.appium.uiautomator2.server.AppiumServlet.handleRequest(AppiumServlet.java:252)
    at io.appium.uiautomator2.server.AppiumServlet.handleHttpRequest(AppiumServlet.java:243)
    at io.appium.uiautomator2.http.ServerHandler.channelRead(ServerHandler.java:44)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:435)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:250)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:611)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysPlain(NioEventLoop.java:514)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:438)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'TAM-NGUYEN', ip: '192.168.1.86', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_231'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
remote stacktrace: NoSuchContextError: org.json.JSONException: No value for desiredCapabilities
    at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
    at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:609)
    at io.appium.uiautomator2.handler.request.BaseRequestHandler.getPayload(BaseRequestHandler.java:50)
    at io.appium.uiautomator2.handler.NewSession.safeHandle(NewSession.java:38)
    at io.appium.uiautomator2.handler.request.SafeRequestHandler.handle(SafeRequestHandler.java:37)
    at io.appium.uiautomator2.server.AppiumServlet.handleRequest(AppiumServlet.java:252)
    at io.appium.uiautomator2.server.AppiumServlet.handleHttpRequest(AppiumServlet.java:243)
    at io.appium.uiautomator2.http.ServerHandler.channelRead(ServerHandler.java:44)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:435)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:250)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:611)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysPlain(NioEventLoop.java:514)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:438)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

    at errorFromMJSONWPStatusCode (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\errors.js:764:12)
    at ProxyRequestError.errorFromMJSONWPStatusCode [as getActualError] (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\errors.js:661:14)
    at JWProxy.getActualError [as command] (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\jsonwp-proxy\proxy.js:259:19)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'TAM-NGUYEN', ip: '192.168.1.86', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_231'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:208)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:217)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:239)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:41)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.startSession(AppiumDriver.java:336)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:37)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:88)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:98)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:94)
    at cucumberOptions.Hooks.openPaxApp(Hooks.java:40)
    at stepDefinitions.RegisterAndLoginSteps.<init>(RegisterAndLoginSteps.java:40)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:186)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: org.json.JSONException: No value for desiredCapabilities
    at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
    at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:609)
    at io.appium.uiautomator2.handler.request.BaseRequestHandler.getPayload(BaseRequestHandler.java:50)
    at io.appium.uiautomator2.handler.NewSession.safeHandle(NewSession.java:38)
    at io.appium.uiautomator2.handler.request.SafeRequestHandler.handle(SafeRequestHandler.java:37)
    at io.appium.uiautomator2.server.AppiumServlet.handleRequest(AppiumServlet.java:252)
    at io.appium.uiautomator2.server.AppiumServlet.handleHttpRequest(AppiumServlet.java:243)
    at io.appium.uiautomator2.http.ServerHandler.channelRead(ServerHandler.java:44)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:435)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:250)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:611)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysPlain(NioEventLoop.java:514)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:438)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'TAM-NGUYEN', ip: '192.168.1.86', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_231'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
remote stacktrace: NoSuchContextError: org.json.JSONException: No value for desiredCapabilities
    at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
    at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:609)
```

Here is the class RegisterAndLoginSteps:

```
package stepDefinitions;

import commons.AbstractPage;
import commons.AbstractTest;
import cucumber.api.DataTable;
import cucumber.api.java.en.And;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
//import cucumberOptions.Hooks;
import cucumberOptions.Hooks;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import pageObjects.HomePO;
import pageObjects.LoginPO;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import static org.testng.Assert.assertTrue;


@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
public class RegisterAndLoginSteps {
    AndroidDriver driver;
    AbstractPage abstractPage;
    LoginPO loginPage;
    HomePO homePage;
    String appTest;

    String packageApp, passCode, defaultCode;

    public RegisterAndLoginSteps() {
        driver = Hooks.openPaxApp("mycar");
        passCode = "7620";
        defaultCode = "1211";

        abstractPage = new AbstractPage(driver);
        loginPage = new LoginPO(driver);
        homePage = new HomePO(driver);

        abstractPage.sendAppPackage();
    }

    @Given("^I logout if currently logged in$")
    public void iLogoutIfCurrentlyLoggedIn() {
        abstractPage.sleepInSecond(1);
        if (loginPage.isCurrentlyLoggedIn()){
            homePage.logout();
        }else{
            loginPage.clickToPhoneNumberTextbox();
        }

    }

    @And("^I select the phone code by \"([^\"]*)\" country$")
    public void iSelectThePhoneCodeByCountry(String countryName) {
        loginPage.selectPhoneCode(countryName);
    }

    @Then("^I verify the passenger register successfully$")
    public void iVerifyThePassengerRegisterSuccessfully() {
        loginPage.clickToSkipButton();
        loginPage.clickToYesNoButton("Yes");
        assertTrue(loginPage.isThereHomeButtonPresent());
    }

    @When("^I select \"([^\"]*)\" server and input \"([^\"]*)\" fleet code$")
    public void iSelectServerAndInputFleetCode(String server, String fleetCode) {
//        loginPage.clickToPhoneNumberTextbox();
        loginPage.longPressToDebugArea();
        loginPage.inputToPassCodeTextbox(passCode);
        loginPage.clickToYesNoButton("YES");
        loginPage.selectServer(server, fleetCode);
        assertTrue(loginPage.isLoginPagePresent());
    }

    @Given("^I click to phone number text box$")
    public void iClickToPhoneNumberTextBox() {

        loginPage.clickToPhoneNumberTextbox();
    }

    @And("^I input the phone number$")
    public void i_input_the_phone_number(DataTable customerTable) {
        List<Map<String, String>> phoneNumber = customerTable.asMaps(String.class, String.class);
        loginPage.inputToPhoneNumberTextbox(phoneNumber.get(0).get("phoneNumber"));
    }


    @And("^I agree with Term of use and Privacy policy$")
    public void iAgreeWithTermOfUseAndPrivacyPolicy() {
        loginPage.clickToAgreeToUAndPolicy();
    }

    @And("^I click to continue button$")
    public void iClickToContinueButton() {
        loginPage.clickToLoginButton();
        loginPage.clickToYesNoButton("Yes");
    }

    @And("^I input sms verify code if have$")
    public void iInputSmsVerifyCodeIfHave(){
        loginPage.inputSMSDefaultCode(defaultCode);
    }

    @And("^I verify register message contains \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void iVerifyRegisterMessageContains(String textContains) {
        assertTrue(loginPage.isWelcomeMsgContains(textContains));
        loginPage.clickToYesNoButton("OK");
    }
}
```

I faced this error only when I trying to run on other devices (these codes still working on my device (Samsung Galaxy S9 - Android 9)

Pls help and thank for your support!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem written here:

*Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: org.json.JSONException: No value for desiredCapabilities*

So to fix this, you need to provide correct capabilities. I don't see `udid` capability, you have to provide it.
**42003cedd0e144d9** - this is `udid` not `deviceName`. `deviceName` could be anything and does not affect anything.

Comment: I still faced this error after changed the "deviceName" to "udid". There are no changes when running the script

Comment: I solved this error by changing the capabilities `skipDeviceInitialization ` and `skipServerInstallation` to "false". Thank for your support

Answer (score 0):

The first line of your stack trace says:

```
Failed to instantiate class stepDefinitions.RegisterAndLoginSteps
```

However, without knowing what's in that class it is hard to know what the cause of the error is.

Comment: I mentioned the wrong class, but the function was same. I define the driver = Hooks.openPaxApp("mycar"). The error navigate me to this code. I was updated the full class RegisterAndLoginSteps on the description. Pls help

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been resolved. 
The error occurs due to the desired capability that I was declared:

```
cap.setCapability("skipDeviceInitialization", "true");
cap.setCapability("skipServerInstallation", "true");
```

In the first time connect to other devices, these capabilities should be "false" to configuration the appium on the Android device. If these capabilities are "true" at the first time we connected to PC, this error will appear.

Thanks for your all support.